# VB Check.changed running on form load and adding to my label

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

I am programming in VB. i need 25 to be added to a variable whenever a checkbox is checked and when it gets unchecked to return it to it's original price. it is working, although whenever my form loads and the checkbox is unchecked it will subtract 25.
here is my code:

If checkbox1.checked then

```
 price += 25
```

else

```
 price -=25
```

end if

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this carefully: [Ask]

Answer (score 0):

Use the event: `CheckBox1_CheckedChanged` instead of putting your code in the event `Load` of the form:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        price += 25
    Else
        price -= 25
    End If
End Sub
```